# Active MQ Shared File System Master Slave with Elastic File System

Tags: amazon-ec2, activemq

I'm setting up Active MQ in production with a shared file system master/slave configuration (KahaDB). I've set everything up and mounted the EFS on both EC2 instances.

When I check the disk free stats I get 8 exabytes for the shared file system:

```
$ df -h
eu-west-1a.***.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E     0  8.0E   0% /mnt/efs
```

Unfortunately, ActiveMQ cannot interpret this number:

```
Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /mnt/efs/kahadb only has -8796093022208 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: -8796093022207 mb
Store limit is -8796093022207 mb, whilst the max journal file size for the store is: 32 mb, the store will not accept any data when used.
```

Which currently prevents its use.

Is there a way to force the OS to report a sensible size for the file system or turn off the FS checking in Active MQ?

Comment: In seems, on further testing, that persistence still works and so does failover. Not sure then what "the store will not accept any data when used." means.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ has made change in 5.15.0 to deal with warning message about EFS.  StoreUsage and TempUsage supported with PercentUsage and if total volume is provided then system will no query the underliying disk size. Please check the updated document at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ACTIVEMQ/Producer+Flow+Control